# Как настроить и работать со snipMate в Vim?

Tags: vi, vim

Подскажите, поставил сейчас snipMate в своем Vim, но... (на youtube все классно и приятно, и я захотел такое...) Поставить - поставил, а что дальше? Как им пользоваться и настроить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я вообще ставил с помощью [pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen), довольно удобная штука, многие в vim-community ею пользуются. Вообще у [Tim Pope](https://github.com/tpope) довольно много полезных vim-плагинов.

После установки в директории `snipplets` будет лежать что-то вроде:

```
autoit.snippets
cpp.snippets
c.snippets
erlang.snippets
eruby-rails_view.snippets
eruby.snippets
html.snippets
javascript.snippets
java.snippets
mako.snippets
objc.snippets
perl.snippets
php.snippets
python.snippets
ruby-factory_girl.snippets
ruby-rails_controller.snippets
ruby-rails_model.snippets
ruby-rails.snippets
ruby-rspec_rails.snippets
ruby-rspec_shoulda_controller.snippets
ruby-rspec_shoulda_model.snippets
ruby-rspec.snippets
ruby-shoulda.snippets
ruby.snippets
ruby-testunit.snippets
sh.snippets
_.snippets
snippet.snippets
tcl.snippets
tex.snippets
vim.snippets
zsh.snippets
```

Поизучайте содержимое этих файлов. Потом в открытом буфере можно будет написать код snippeta + TAB. В режиме вставки.

Разумеется в эти файлы можно дописывать свои snippets. Синтаксис прост.

**UPD**:

Работа сниппетов зависит от определения типа файла, может поэтому у вас не работает. Попробуйте задать насильно `set ft=c` или что-нибудь в этом роде. Кроме того в мануале советуют дописать `filetype plugin on` .vimrc.

Вы ставили с помощью pathogen или без?

Comment: дело в том,что у меня сейчас стоит один snipmate без дополнений,но когда пытаюсь например написать for потом нажимаю[tab] и ничего не происходит!  
готов выложить конфиги vim какие надо,но мне уж очень нужен этот плагин.

Comment: Ставил чистый snipMate без Patogen и в vimrc дописал:  

    filetype on filetype plugin on  

Вот мой файл vimrc:http://dl.dropbox.com/u/23843821/temp/vimrc.txt

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы snipmate знал, какие сниппеты использовать - нужно загружать уже сохраненные файлы с расширением. Например,

```
touch index.html # Создать файл
vim index.html
```

Или ***vim index.html***, но перед тем как пользоваться snipmate, просто сохранить файл - ***:write*** (***:w*** коротко).
В этом случае snipmate будет знать, что сниппеты брать из файла сниппетов для HTML (которые находятся в файле ***~/.vim/snippets/html.snippets***)